# Select statement Oracle with tree

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a 2 tables **regions** and **communities**

**REGIONS**:

```
ID        REGION_NAME
1         Erevan
2         Tavush
```

and

**COMMUNITIES**:

```
ID        REGION_ID       COMMUNITY_NAME
1             1             SHENGAVIT
2             1             DAVTASHEN
3             1             EREBUNI
4             2              ANUN
5             2             AZGANUN
```

I want to select and get result like this:

```
REGION_NAME         COMMUNITY_NAME
------------------------------------
EREVAN
                    SHENGAVIT
                    DAVTASHEN
                    EREBUNI
TAVUSH
                    ANUN
                    AZGANUN
```

Please help will solve the problem

Comment: Take a look at the CONNECT BY clause

Comment: @OldProgrammer - what does CONNECT BY have to do with this?

Comment: what tool do you use? sqlplus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of requirement should be solved in the reporting layer, not in SQL. However, if you absolutely must do it in SQL, you could do something like this. Note that, since you don't need to show the region name in each "community" row, there is no need for joins; a `union all` suffices. The solution assumes community id's are always positive (so that an artificial value of 0 would always come first in ordering - see below).

```
with
     regions ( id, region_name ) as (
       select 1, 'Erevan' from dual union all
       select 2, 'Tavush' from dual
     ),
     communities ( id, region_id, community_name ) as (
       select 1, 1, 'shengavit' from dual union all
       select 2, 1, 'davtashen' from dual union all
       select 3, 1, 'erebuni'   from dual union all
       select 4, 2, 'anun'      from dual union all
       select 5, 2, 'azganun'   from dual
     )
-- End of test data (not part of the solution). Query begins below this line.
select   region_name, community_name
from     (
           select id as r_id, 0 as c_id, region_name, null as community_name
             from regions
           union all
           select region_id as r_id, id as c_id, null as region_name, community_name
             from communities
         )
order by r_id, c_id
;

REGION_NAME  COMMUNITY_NAME
-----------  --------------
Erevan
             shengavit
             davtashen
             erebuni
Tavush
             anun
             azganun
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select REGION_NAME, COMMUNITY_NAME from (
    select REGION_NAME, ' ' as COMMUNITY_NAME, id as regid, 0 as ord from REGIONS
    union all
    select ' ' as REGION_NAME, COMUNITIES.COMMUNITY_NAME, COMUNITIES.REGION_ID as regid, COMUNITIES.ID as ord
    from REGIONS
    inner join COMUNITIES
    on REGIONS.id = COMUNITIES.REGION_ID
) t
order by regid, ord
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.community_name 
FROM communities c 
INNER JOIN regions r ON r.id = c.region_id 
GROUP BY r.region_name;
```

Comment: Did you mean order by? Also, the OP wanted the region name as well, where is it in your query?

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use [SQL*Plus](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQPUG/formatting-SQL-Plus-reports.htm#SQPUG491). I was not able to produce exactly the output you want but only a similar one.

This is a master/slave or parent/child relation but not a tree structure.

```
select R.REGION_NAME, C.COMMUNITY_NAME
from REGIONS R, COMMUNITIES C
where R.ID = C.REGION_ID
order by R.ID, C.ID
/
```

This will result in

```
REGION_NAME          COMMUNITY_NAME
-------------------- ----------------
EREVAN               SHENGAVIT
EREVAN               DAVTASHEN
EREVAN               EREBUNI
TAVUSH               ANUN
TAVUSH               AZGANUN
```

You can use SQL*Plus commands to format the output. Use the `break on REGION_NAME` command to supress the repeating printing of the REGION_NAME values and get

```
REGION_NAME          COMMUNITY_NAME
-------------------- ----------------
EREVAN               SHENGAVIT
                     DAVTASHEN
                     EREBUNI
TAVUSH               ANUN
                     AZGANUN
```

or use the `break on REGION_NAME skip 1` command to get

```
REGION_NAME          COMMUNITY_NAME
-------------------- ----------------
EREVAN               SHENGAVIT
                     DAVTASHEN
                     EREBUNI

TAVUSH               ANUN
                     AZGANUN
```

So to generate this output with SQL*Plus you have to execute

```
break on REGION_NAME skip 1

select R.REGION_NAME, C.COMMUNITY_NAME
from REGIONS R, COMMUNITIES C
where R.ID = C.REGION_ID
order by R.ID, C.ID
/
```

Please note that these SQL*Plus format commands are available in SQL*Plus but not in other clients. They are not part of the SQL language.